# Android SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, bitmap

I download a image from server and save the same in SD Card.

When I try to fetch the same using my code, it gives an Error `SkImageDecoder:: Factory returned null`

Please help me...

My code to read the file is as below:

```
try{
    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString(); 
    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();     
    extStorageDirectory = extStorageDirectory + "/egnuri/456.png";  
    // egnuri is directory name. and 456.png is imagename.

    Bitmap loadimage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(extStorageDirectory);
    imView.setImageBitmap(loadimage);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1. Please check it if the file is present using file.exists(extStorageDirectory) before you load image

Comment: 1. Open SDCard, Directory and your file as File Object.    2. Before you make a call to Load image, check if the file exists.

Comment: There could be a physical problem with your SD card. Try saving the image to your device and re-testing.

Comment: @Vinay, thanks for the heads up. In my case the file was there but empty.